# ng-click on img not working inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

In my view I have a list of icons that when clicked, should call a function from the controller.

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="EditorController" class="main-div">
  <aside>
   <div ng-repeat="icon in EditorIcons">
     <img ng-click="changeme()"
     data-ng-src="{{icon.source}}"
     alt="{{icon.name}}"/>

   </div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
  app.controller('EditorController', function($scope) {
    $scope.EditorIcons = [ ... ];
    $scope.changeme = function() {
       console.log("changing");
    }
  }
```

I've seen this question asked before, yet I still wasn't able to find out the problem here. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I've found the problem. I had a z-index of -1 on the aside element

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `EditorIcons` is a collection in your controller, and `changeme` is a method inside of your controller, the  you need t remove the `$parent`:

```
<div ng-repeat="icon in EditorIcons">
  <img ng-click="changeme()"
    ng-src="{{icon.source}}" alt="{{icon.name}}" />
</div>
```

Secondry you werte missing quotes `"` in your `alt` definition

Comment: I removed $parent, but still nothing. I also updated my answer

Comment: So your images are being displayed, but there is no click possible? Maybe the problem is your image is not visible, so clicling does not work, try moving ng-click to the div instead and then try.

Comment: Images are visible, there is no problem there. I've tried to put the function on the ng-repeat div, but still nothing. However, if I call this function on a div after the aside element it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just tried to make a fiddle and it works fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/8807dvrr/2/

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
    <aside>
      <div ng-repeat="icon in EditorIcons">
        <img ng-click="changeme()" data-ng-src="{{icon.source}}" alt="{{icon.name}}" />
      </div>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>



 function SomeCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.EditorIcons = [{
    source: '',
    name: 'icon-1'
  }, {
    source: '',
    name: 'icon-2'
  }];
  $scope.changeme = function() {
    console.log("changing");
  }
};
```

So your problem has to be somewhere in declaration of controller or ng-app since code works, also check that data you have in editor icons is good.

Comment: share your entire code in jsfiddle or at least here.

Comment: I removed $parent, but still nothing. I also updated my answer

Comment: right now I see that you're missing one </div> try my html

Comment: Fixed that, but still no result

Comment: check my answer now, also make sure that data is correct (that you have properties source and name on each icon in your array)

Comment: Thank you for your help. After banging my head up against the walls a few times, I found my problem: I had a z-index of -1 on the aside element

Comment: Yeah good thing you found your solution, next time include CSS as well when you're presenting your code;)